# Dexie updates to a table with 2 compound keys get very slow in iOS

Tags: ios, performance, dexie

I am trying to sort out a performance issue in doing a data restore on iOS (i.e. data exists in a table, then I update some of it from a flat file backup).  My actual case is 1250 times slower on iOS than Windows.  I started with the raindrops example from Dexie.bulkPut, which does not exhibit this behavior (it's slower, but only by about 15%, and gradually modified it to be more like what I need to do.

What I have found is that if my table has a single compound key, I can bulkPut the data twice, and it takes nearly the same amount of time both times.  But if there are two compound keys, the second write takes about the same time on the computer, but much, much longer on iOS (times in seconds).

```
                 Windows         Windows          iOS            iOS
    Records      First write     Second write     First write    Second write
     20,000        2.393           1.904           5.057          131.127
     40,000        5.231           3.941           9.533          509.616
     60,000        7.808           8.331          14.188         1205.181
```

Here is my test program:

```
var db = new Dexie("test");
db.delete().then(function() {
    db.version(1).stores({
        raindrops: '[matrix+row+col], [matrix+done]'
    });
    db.open();
    var t1 = new Date();
    var drops = [];
    for (var i=0;i<20000;++i) { // make a matrix
        drops.push({matrix: 0, row: Math.floor(i/100)+1, col: i % 100 +1, done: i%2});
    }
    db.raindrops.bulkPut(drops).then(function(lastKey) {
        t2 = new Date();
        console.log("Time in seconds " + (t2.getTime() - t1.getTime())/1000);
        db.raindrops.bulkPut(drops).then(function(lastKey) {
            t3 = new Date();
            console.log("Reputting -- Time in seconds " + (t3.getTime() - t2.getTime())/1000);
        });
    });
});
```

I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions.  I need that second index but I also need for people to be able to do a restore in finite time (my users are not very careful about clearing browser data).  Is there any chance of this performance improving?  The fact that it's so much better for Windows suggests that it doesn't HAVE to be that way.  Or is there a way I could drop the second index before doing a restore and then re-indexing?  Done is 0 or 1 and that index is there so I can get a quick count of records with done set (or not set), but maybe it would be better to count manually.

Comment: I decided to drop the second index, but am leaving this open because I do think the performance (whether it's Dexie or the iOS implementation of indexedDB) could stand a look.

Comment: I should have said, this was tested using Dexie 3.0.0.rc-4.  I was trying to fix a performance problem which involved updating records one at a time, using 2.0.4, and bulkPut did speed it up a lot.